# Split data in text file use pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv, split, export-to-csv

I have a text file, for example:

```
The first day
A   B   C
1   4   6
3   2   7
The second day
A   B   C
3   6   7
7   9   0
The last day
A   B   C
3   5   2
4   7   0
```

Then i need to convert it to csv file as:

```
A   B   C   Day
1   4   6   The first day
3   2   7   The first day
3   6   7   The second day
7   9   0   The second day
3   5   2   The last day
4   7   0   The last day
```

I don't know to do. Help me, pleaseeee

Comment: Are the "The X day" literals?

Comment: don't use images

Comment: Is there any pattern to read the separator lines like "The xyz day"? Or is there any fixed header like "A  B  C"?